# vDSP_conv occasionally returns NANs

Tags: swift, swift2, signal-processing

I'm using `vDSP_conv` to perform autocorrelation. Mostly it works just fine but every so often it's filling the output array with NaNs.

The code:

```
func corr_test() {
  var pass = 0

  var x = [Float]()
  for i in 0..<2000 {
    x.append(Float(i))
  }

  while true {
    print("pass \(pass)")

    let corr = autocorr(x)
    if corr[1].isNaN {
        print("!!!")
    }
    pass += 1
  }
}

func autocorr(a: [Float]) -> [Float] {
    let resultLen = a.count * 2 + 1
    let padding = [Float].init(count: a.count, repeatedValue: 0.0)
    let a_pad = padding + a + padding
    var result = [Float].init(count: resultLen, repeatedValue: 0.0)

    vDSP_conv(a_pad, 1, a_pad, 1, &result, 1, UInt(resultLen), UInt(a_pad.count))

    return result
}
```

The output:

```
pass ...
pass 169
pass 170
pass 171
(lldb) p corr
([Float]) $R0 = 4001 values {
  [0] = 2.66466637E+9
  [1] = NaN
  [2] = NaN
  [3] = NaN
  [4] = NaN
...
```

I'm not sure what's going on here. I think I'm handling the 0 padding correctly since if I weren't I don't think I'd be getting correct results 99% of the time.

Ideas? Gracias.

Comment: The docs say that vector A "must be at least N + P - 1." N is the length of the output vector and P is the length of the filter vector, so the way I'm padding the array is probably wrong, but I'm still not sure what the right method is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The key was this comment from https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/vDSPExamples/Listings/DemonstrateConvolution_c.html :

```
// “The signal length is padded a bit. This length is not actually passed to the vDSP_conv routine; it is the number of elements
// that the signal array must contain. The SignalLength defined below is used to allocate space, and it is the filter length
// rounded up to a multiple of four elements and added to the result length. The extra elements give the vDSP_conv routine
// leeway to perform vector-load instructions, which load multiple elements even if they are not all used. If the caller did not
// guarantee that memory beyond the values used in the signal array were accessible, a memory access violation might result.”
```

“Padded a bit.” Thanks for being so specific. Anyway here's the final working product:

```
func autocorr(a: [Float]) -> [Float] {
let filterLen = a.count
let resultLen = filterLen * 2 - 1
let signalLen = ((filterLen + 3) & 0xFFFFFFFC) + resultLen

let padding1 = [Float].init(count: a.count - 1, repeatedValue: 0.0)
let padding2 = [Float].init(count: (signalLen - padding1.count - a.count), repeatedValue: 0.0)
let signal = padding1 + a + padding2

var result = [Float].init(count: resultLen, repeatedValue: 0.0)

vDSP_conv(signal, 1, a, 1, &result, 1, UInt(resultLen), UInt(filterLen))

// Remove the first n-1 values which are just mirrored from the end so that [0] always has the autocorrelation.
result.removeFirst(filterLen - 1)

return result
}
```

Note that the results here aren't normalized.